# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

Tags: python, python-2.7, yahoo-finance

I'm getting an URL Error when running this code -

```
    import yahoo_finance as yf

    yahoo = yf.Share('YHOO')
    d=yahoo.get_historical('2014-05-19', '2014-05-20')
    print "A week of stock daily quotations:"
    for e in d:
        print e
    print "Info about the company:",yahoo.get_info()
    print "Market capitalization in dollars:",yahoo.get_market_cap()
```

[image]

ERROR - Please Help me with this

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Comment: This code does not directly call `urlopen()`, so the error must be happening elsewhere in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: This is the only code im running ,nothing else

Comment: You sure this is not an internet connection error? Maybe you've configured the anaconda setup wrong.

Comment: You could also try [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery). Can get historical data as well as anything else you can imagine from the Yahoo Finance front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo provided the EOD financial data service for a long time but it was terminated back in 2017. You might want to check other ways to retrieve this information such as using https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance-api2/.